# Interpretation of user page features

Tags: discussion, support

I hope I chose the correct tags...

On my user page there is a section listing questions I have participated in with numbers to the left of the question description:

[image]

What do the numbers mean?

Comment: rep gained on those questions, apparently from answers

Comment: @Plutonix - Total rep from _all_ participants?

Comment: see below for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is how much reputation you got from that question. The +33 means that you got +15 for the answer being accepted, +20 from two upvotes, and -2 from one down vote. The +10 is from 1 upvote and it is not green because the answer was not accepted.

This is just the combined score on each question. For more specific information, you can visit your reputation page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/645128/ryyker?tab=reputation